# Importing into remote repo using artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I have a zip file which has many dependencies. How can i import this zip file into a remote repository using artifactory. What is the file structure that needs to be maintained to import all the dependencies in the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

You can import one or more repositories from a zip file into Artifactory.
For a single repository the imported repository needs to be formatted using a Maven 2 repository layout.
For more information about import/exporting repositories see [this page](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting).